# Ruby - where is the attribute definition here?

Tags: ruby, attributes

Where is the attribute `@color` defined here? Presumably the assignment in the constructor? If this is the case, what if a type has multiple constructors, one of which does not assign a value to `@color`?

```
class Baz
  def initialize(color)
    @color = color
  end

  def color
    @color
  end

  def color=(value)
    @color = value
  end
end
```

Comment: Note: In ruby you can not define multiple initializers for a class. You can define initializer with default values, e.g. `def initialize(color = 'FFFFFF')`. When you will call `Baz.new` without parameter, then default value will be assigned to `@color`

Comment: I posted an answer to your question, but I think it's also useful to note separately that ruby has a nifty pattern that easily lets you create robust interfaces to your instance variables without exposing the class internals. See here for details on that: http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html

Comment: A nice advantage of using these attribute accessors is that it allows you to later define the methods manually if you need to add more complex functionality than simple getters/setters. It also just saves typing. In your example code, instead of defining the `color` and `color=` methods, you could just write `attr_accessor :color` and get the setter/getter methods automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance variables in ruby are not "defined" per se. They pop into existence when they are used.

The first time you assign something to an instance variable, that is the closest thing to a "definition" (but really it is more of an "initialization"). If you reference an instance variable that has not been assigned a value yet, its value will be `nil`.

So if your constructor does not assign a value to `@color`, then `@color` will simply remain uninitialized (and thus return `nil` anywhere else in the class that references it...unless it is assigned a value elsewhere outside the constructor).

See here for more information: http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html

A relevant quote from the article:

> Instance variables do not need to be declared. This indicates a
>   flexible object structure; in fact, each instance variable is
>   dynamically appended to an object when it is first assigned.

And:

> As with globals, instance variables have the nil value until they are
>   initialized.

Answer (score 2):

> what if a type has multiple constructors, one of which does not assign a value to @color

Well, then those instances won't have a `@color` instance variable, and operations on that variable are likely to fail.

Hopefully good design and testing will reduce the number of those cases to zero, but it's not something that the language itself protects you against.

Note that in your specific example this shouldn't be a problem because the only operations are setting (which is clearly fine) and getting, which is also fine - retrieving instance variables will return `nil` if the variable has never been set.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that there can only be one `initialize` method in a class because Ruby does not support method overloading.